# Ругательство Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Вообщем, ситауция такая - лежит себе спокойно проект для курсового(тестировал, всё работает). Решаю зайти, проверить и вижу что не прогружается одна из активностей.
Соседняя активность работает и все элементы показываются. Ошибок(кроме тех, что на скриншоте) не показывает. Товарищи знатоки, помогите, пожалуйста!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тупой совет, но если всё работало, то обновите студию, откройте её заново, пересобирите проект. Иногда почему-то студия ведёт себя неадекватно, а потом всё само чинится. И вы же пробовали обновить разметку как рекомендуют в ошибке?

Comment: Макет кривой, в лист инфа суётся через адаптер. А вообше оно устарело и надо юзать RecyclerView

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как оно у вас могло работать раньше, но сейчас `TextView` стоит внутри `ListView` - так делать нельзя, `ListView` не поддерживает произвольное добавление элементов.
Если вам нужно что-то закрепить именно внутри списка - используйте хедеры/футеры, если снаружи - вынесите выше или ниже самого `ListView` в общий контейнер